# NFS delays renames but not writes?

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, rename

I have some (6) boxes that have an NFS share mounted on which they write files. All run ubuntu 14.01 and the NFS server is a standard nfs-server from ubuntu packages. This works well.

However, when renaming files on the share by one system, it can take around half a minute before the other systems see the rename. Calling sync on the client after the rename doesn't help. Is this delayed write caching in action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `actimeo` to a lower value in your fstab file and remount.

Comment: That helped a little, files appeared faster, but even at actimeo=0 it was still not fast enough. Maybe I should switch to another shared FS.

Comment: @glormph You did set this option on both systems right ? This should lower the behaviour you see to one second if `actimeo=1`. If you don't want any file attribute caching client-side set the `noac` option. Be aware that it makes writes synchronous thus brings a performance penalty. Are you running a caching daemon like FS-Cache at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, on both systems. Setting actimeo to 1 seems to work perfectly well with files in a test script though, they get renamed almost instantly, so thanks for the tip and I'll accept. But confused, it's like extra caching happens just for that process. Will maybe solve it very badly with a call to sleep or something.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for Java (tested in 17.0.2): In my case, doing

```
origFile.renameTo(bckFile);
newFile.renameTo(origFile));
```

on one unix machine shows a delay of 10..30 seconds on seeing changes in `origFile` on a second unix machine if the files are saved on a NFS partition.

The delay disappeared after resolving the renames:

```
copyFileFromTo(origFile, bckFile);
copyFileFromTo(newFile, origFile);
newFile.delete();
```